# In ruby on rails 3 is a database only accessible from a user_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is it possible to pull a user object from any controller? For me it seems to only work in my users controller.

I'm trying to render a form that a user can use to update the details they signed up to the website with e.g. names, email, password etc. The problem is the page won't load (it is called using .load jquery function). It won't load when the form is added to the page but will load when it isn't there. I'm thinking it's something to do with it not being able to access the database.

In my pages controller I have this:

```
def edit_account

    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    case params[:view]
      when 'basic_info'
        render 'pages/settings/basic_info'
      when 'relatives'
        render 'pages/settings/relatives'
    end

    @title = "My Account"
  end
```

It doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?
@user object works fine in user_controller and it's associated views but not in pages controller. Is there a way to give pages controller access?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using proper REST methods, the id will be the id of the page not the id of the user.

What you can do is

```
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

And if pages and users are related (ie a page belongs to a user), you can do:

```
@user = @page.user
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm sure I'm doing it incorrectly. How ever in my edit method in users controller when I add the form to the template it pulls the users database info which is what I want.. But I want to do this inside the pages controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can access `User` from any controller.

However the way you find the user will differ depending on what `params` you have available to pass to `User.find`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the wrong params key in controller other than UsersController.  In other controllers the params would be `user_id`. So...

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

#### Just as a note about the rest of the code.

The use of view is just wrong here. Create separate actions for your views (if you aren't trying to be RESTful).  It is harder to maintain when the view are handled inside a single method.  It would be better to say:

```
def basic_info
  view_defaults
end

def relatives
  view_defaults
end

private 

def view_defaults
    @user  = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @title = "My Account"
end
```

And set the proper routes to connect these actions.